# How to go to a certain previous instance of an activity that calls explicit intents to itself

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have an activity  [A]  that has an explicit intent to itself

So the navigation goes this way :-

[A] > [A:instance1]> [A:instance2] > [A:instance3]  > want to

go back to [A:instance1]

Of course with the regular back button I go from [A:instance3] back to [A:instance2] .I tried overriding that method but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest way is calling `finish()` at some point. This *some point* can be

- the activity itself when it fires the next one, if appropriate
- the activity itself when resumed

The second alternative needs a flag in the session memory. You could extend the `Application` class and add methods like `MyApp.setFinishOnResume(data)`. As a implementation aid, note that you need a flag for each activity that will call `finish()`, and the flag must be cleared after that call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer The finish() worked in getting me back to the instance before [B] but I found out I need to go further back to the instance before that instance instead .I don't know about flags .so I will be really grateful  if you could post a code for the back Button.

Comment: Extend Application and add methods to save the session state. Then set/get/clear state when appropriate inside callbacks like onResume() and/or user input listeners